# How to get DirectoryInfo for a Onedrive folder with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, onedrive, system.io.directory

I have some code that uses System.IO to find files with a given extension. This works fine with regular folders but fails when the files are in Onedrive's local cache.

My assumption is that the problem is to do with the Onedrive cache folder because if the files are moved out of Onedrive and into a local folder e.g. c:\temp, it all works fine.

```
Dim Folder As New IO.DirectoryInfo(TextBox_RootFolder.Text)
Filelist = Folder.GetFiles("*.xlsx", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

This is VB, so I believe there should *not* be any issues with string literals, so I'm stumped.

The path string comes out as something similar to: **"C:\Users\user\OneDrive - ThisPlace\MyFolder"** so there's nothing particularly weird about the string.

When presented with a folder on Onedrive, my variable 'Folder' is correctly assigned with the full path but an exception is thrown on calling **Folder.Getfiles**. This results in the error *"The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid"*.

BTW, I'm a novice so example code would be really appreciated as a detailed technical explanation is likely to go whoosh over my head.

Comment: Whenever you ask a question, you ALWAYS need to explain exactly what does happen, not just that it isn't what you expect.

Comment: You are correct that the issue is around onedrive, in fact you will have similar issues on any cloud sync drive (Google Drive, iCloud, DropBox etc).  Using OneDrive does require a little more work than local disk io.  Have a look over https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/sample-code?view=odsp-graph-online

Comment: Apologies for not describing the error thrown. I have updated the question to include details. Thanks to @Hursey for the link. I have had a quick look at one of the samples but have yet to work out how I can get around this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm please to report that I found an easy way to solve the problem.

Firstly I retained the code that uses **Folder.Getfiles** to provide a list of files as this is fast, elegant and retrieves files in sub-folders.

It still throws an exception when it encounters a cloud sync folder such as Onedrive, DropBox etc., so in the **catch** I use the **Dir()** function to loop through the files as this does not have problems with folders of this type.

Here is some pseudo-code to show an example:

```
Dim sFile As String  
sFile = Dir(sPath + "\*.xlsx")  
Do While sFile <> ""
  [ do stuff here ]
  sFile = Dir() '' Get the next file  
Loop
```

I hope this is helpful to someone.